# Inversely proportional proof

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, total-variation

Let $$y \propto \frac{1}{x}$$

Then we know y is inversely proportional to x.
Then,

Why is y is inversely proportional to x same as $y \propto \frac{1}{x}$.

My attempt to prove this:-

Let $k$ be the constant of proportionality.

Then, if $y \propto x$ then multiplying k by x would increase y at the rate of k.

> But, What if x is negative?

And also dividing k by x would reduce y.

But in the above statement I am not sure why would it reduce it by the ***same rate***?

And also is it possible to x be a fraction and y increase?

I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the inverse of $\space x\space$ is
$\space\dfrac{1}{x}\space$ also shown as
$\space x^{-1}.\space$

In humanspeak, that means saying

"$\space y\space $ is proportional to the inverse of $\space x$" $\quad$
is the same as saying

"$\space y\space $ is inversely proportional to
$\space x.$"

For the staement about negative x, proportionality refers to magnitude, independent of sign.

In your statement about $k, \space \space k \space$ does not affect proportionality except for the first iteration. The ratio $y:xk\space$ always  stays the same.

Comment: Can you tell would it vary at the same rate and decrease of y is inversely proportional to x.

Comment: @Mohd Saad   The $k$-value would increase or degrease a rate of change for y but the ratio y:(1/kx) would always be the same.

Comment: Okay, So That means they would vary at same rate